# Recursive display select option in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a html select tag with option tags like below:

```html
<select> 
<option value="">Parent 1</option> 
<option value=1>|--child 1</option> 
<option value=2>|----child 1.1</option>
<option value=2>|----child 1.2</option>
<option value=1>|--child 2</option>     
  
<option value="">Parent 2</option> 
<option value=1>|--child 2</option> 
<option value=2>|----child 2.1</option> 
  
<option value="">Parent 3</option> 
<option value=1>|--child 3</option> 
<option value=2>|----child 3.1</option>   
</select>
```

Could you please teach me how to implement this recursive in Angularjs 1 directive ?
And how can i get selected item when in Editable mode?

Thank you very much.

Khoa Truong Quoc Anh.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<optgroup>` with ng-select

```
 <select ng-model='theModel' ng-change="display(theModel)">
        <optgroup ng-repeat='group in collection' label="{{group.Name}}">
        <option ng-repeat='veh in group.Fields' value='{{group.Name}}::{{veh.Name}}'>{{veh.Name}}</option>
        </optgroup>
 </select>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/abKJIGwRAz56h7hHXOfS?p=preview)

Comment: When I try to add more deeply structure like this:
"Name": "Parent2",
                  "Fields": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Field1",
                        "Fields": [
                          {
                              "Name": "Field1.1"
                          },
                          {
                              "Name": "Field2.1"
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                  ]
The name 'Field1.1' didn't render for me,
I want to have RECURSIVE options here.
Thanks Sajeetharan.

Comment: Display Like what?

Comment: your json is not fomated coectly update in the plunke and give the link

Comment: The new updated formated correct json as below:

{"Collections": [{"Name": "Parent1","Fields": [{"Name": "Field1"                   },{"Name": "Field2"},{"Name": "Field3"}]},{"Name": "Parent2",             "Fields": [{"Name": "Field1","Fields": [{"Name": "Field1.1",                             "Fields": [{"Name": "Field1.1.1"},{"Name": "Field1.1.2"}]},{                              "Name": "Field1.2"}]},{"Name": "Field2"}]}]}

Answer (score 1):

Syntax:

```
ng-options="option.name as option.value group by option.type for option in options"
```

[Click for demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XcTscLtfyaYgbYr2TcT4?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Gani, but your solution is just showing 2 levels.
How can i show the 3rd, 4th... level if i have more data?